# AWS user-migration Lambda won't create a user in Cognito

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-cognito, serverless

For some reason I can no longer get my `user-migration` to create a user in Cognito. I've paired it back to the most basic:

```
    def migration_handler(event, context):

        # Create the user in Cognito
        event["response"]["userAttributes"] = {
            "username": event["userName"],
            "email": event["userName"],
            # "email_verified": True,
            # "custom:nutrinoId": 'nutrino_id',
            # 'custom:finished-signup': 'true'
        }
        event["response"]["finalUserStatus"] = "CONFIRMED"
        event["response"]["messageAction"] = "SUPPRESS"

        return event
```

I'm using Serverless (v2.72.2) to publish, which all seems fine as the migration handler fires. Here are the Cloudwatch logs from an `InitiateAuth` attempt:

| timestamp | message |
| --- | --- |
| 1643820943789 | START RequestId: 7381165c-88b7-4a57-98b2-28abc8a53abe Version: $LATEST |
| 1643820943789 | [INFO] 2022-02-02T16:55:43.789Z Found credentials in environment variables. |
| 1643820943884 | [INFO] 2022-02-02T16:55:43.884Z 7381165c-88b7-4a57-98b2-28abc8a53abe Migration Lambda. Event: {'version': '1', 'triggerSource': 'UserMigration_Authentication', 'region': 'us-west-2', 'userPoolId': 'us-west-2_xxx', 'userName': 'TestUserName_361732910030@gmail.com', 'callerContext': {'awsSdkVersion': 'aws-sdk-unknown-unknown', 'clientId': 'xxx'}, 'request': {'password': 'TestPassword', 'validationData': None, 'userAttributes': None}, 'response': {'userAttributes': None, 'forceAliasCreation': None, 'finalUserStatus': None, 'messageAction': None, 'desiredDeliveryMediums': None}} |
| 1643820943884 | [DEBUG] 2022-02-02T16:55:43.884Z 7381165c-88b7-4a57-98b2-28abc8a53abe Final Event: {'version': '1', 'triggerSource': 'UserMigration_Authentication', 'region': 'us-west-2', 'userPoolId': 'us-west-2_xxx', 'userName': 'TestUserName_361732910030@gmail.com', 'callerContext': {'awsSdkVersion': 'aws-sdk-unknown-unknown', 'clientId': 'xxx'}, 'request': {'password': 'TestPassword', 'validationData': None, 'userAttributes': None}, 'response': {'userAttributes': {'username': 'TestUserName_361732910030@gmail.com'}, 'forceAliasCreation': None, 'finalUserStatus': 'CONFIRMED', 'messageAction': 'SUPPRESS', 'desiredDeliveryMediums': None}} |
| 1643820943885 | END RequestId: 7381165c-88b7-4a57-98b2-28abc8a53abe |
| 1643820943885 | REPORT RequestId: 7381165c-88b7-4a57-98b2-28abc8a53abe Duration: 1.74 ms Billed Duration: 2 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB Max Memory Used: 65 MB Init Duration: 797.46 ms |

As far as I can see it, the final event object returned in the lambda should create the user but I get a `NotAuthorizedException: Incorrect username or password.` exception from boto and the user isn't listed in my User Pool.

As you can see there are no error messages in the lambda logs.

Any ideas, or tips on further investigation?

Comment: In the code you shared there is no call to cognito. All I can see is you editing the event object and returning it.

Comment: Isn't that what Step 4 implies you should do here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-import-using-lambda.html

Comment: @HariHonor which *User authentication operations* are you using and is `PreventUserExistenceErrors` enabled? As well, if you tune your python script to interpret `UserMigration_Authentication` and `UserMigration_ForgotPassword` and an `else` part in the code, what do you get? Refer the NodeJS code [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-migrate-user.html) at the last

Comment: Is there anything in Cognito CloudTrail? After your Lambda returns there should be an API call to Cognito, can you check what's in there? I guess that this is the place where you get NotAuthorizedException from AdminCreateUser request.

Answer (score 0):

In the standard attributes there's no `username` field. It should be `name` instead.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html#user-pool-settings-custom-attributes.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34546696)